# Finding information on Baseball-Reference using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I hope you are all doing well.

I am trying to locate the "Other Info" section of this page: 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/COL/COL202104060.shtml#all_play_by_play'. I would like to incorporate the information into a model I am building. However, I cannot seem to locate it with BS4. I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
web_page = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/COL/COL202104060.shtml#all_play_by_play'
page = requests.get(web_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
child_soup = soup.find_all('strong')
```

As well as this:

```
soup.find_all('<strong>Umpires:</strong>')
```

The second one I was just trying to find the content, but still no luck. Finally, I tried this:
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

```
text = 'Umpires:'
gfg = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "strong" and text in tag.text)
print(gfg)
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: I was going to suggest https://pypi.org/project/sportsreference/ as an alternative to scraping the webpage yourself, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was bit of a trick as `Umpires:` is coming up as HTML comment. so the following code does the track, comment is added with the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment # comment added to import
import requests
web_page = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/COL/COL202104060.shtml#all_play_by_play'
page = requests.get(web_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'lxml')
other_info=soup.find_all("h2", string="Other Info")[0].parent.parent # access other section , i.e parent of parent
# other section is coming up as comment, so let's extract the comment and then make its soup :)
commeted_section=other_info.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))[0] # extract comment
commeted_section_soup = BeautifulSoup(commeted_section , 'lxml') # make comment soup
commeted_section_soup.find_all("div")[0].text.replace("\n","").split(":")[1]
```

output

```
' HP - Bill Welke, 1B - Chris Conroy, 2B - Pat Hoberg, 3B - Ben May, LF - (none), RF - (none).Time of Game'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Editing the number after 'commeted_section_soup.find_all("div")[0].text.replace("\n","").split(":")[1]' yields the rest of the information too! Thank you again!